# How to find strings with delimiter and replace them with new lines in pandas dataframe Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to figure out how to solve following problem:

I have pandas dataframe that contains some strings that are delimited with ','. My goal is to find these and replace them with new lines so that there are no more delimiters within the dataframe. For example a cell contains 'hi,there' and I would like it to become 'hi' and 'there' so there will be two lines instead of one at the end.

This should be applied until there are no delimiters within original dataframe so in case there are two words ('hi,there' and 'whats,up,there') in one line in two different columns, it becomes 6 lines instead of original one (cartesian product). The same should be applied for all lines within dataframe.

Here below is code demonstrating the original dataframe (a) and the result I would like to end with:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([['Hi,there', 'fv', 'whats,up,there'],['dfasd', 'vfgfh', 'kutfddx'],['fdfa', 'uyg', 'iutyfrd']], columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Output:
[image]

Desired output here:

[image]

So far I managed to copy the lines so many times I need for this purpose but I cannot figure out how to replace the delimited words with what I want:

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame([])
for i in a.values:
    n = 1
    for j in i:
        if ',' in j:
            n = n*len(j.split(','))
    ndf = ndf.append([i]*n, ignore_index=False)
```

This produces:
[image]

Any idea how to proceed? I can only use pandas and numpy for this but I am convinced it should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I split by coma words then use `stack()` function

```
a_list = a.apply(lambda x : x.str.split(','))

for i in a_list:
    tmp = pd.DataFrame.from_records(a_list[i].tolist()).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('new_{}'.format(i))
    a = a.drop(i, axis=1).join(tmp)

a = a.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
>>> a
   new_a    new_c  new_b
0     Hi    whats     fv
1     Hi       up     fv
2     Hi    there     fv
3  there    whats     fv
4  there       up     fv
5  there    there     fv
6  dfasd  kutfddx  vfgfh
7   fdfa  iutyfrd    uyg
```

**Update**

To handle missing values (`np.nan` and `None`) first I convert it to string then do the same as for normal data and then I replace *NaN* string to `np.nan`.

Let's insert some missing values

```
import numpy as np
a['a'].loc[0] = np.nan
a['b'].loc[1] = None

#        a     b               c
# 0    NaN    fv  whats,up,there
# 1  dfasd  None         kutfddx
# 2   fdfa   uyg         iutyfrd

a.fillna('NaN', inplace=True) # some string

#
# insert the code above (with for loop)
#

a.replace('NaN', np.nan, inplace=True)

#    new_a new_b    new_c
# 0    NaN    fv    whats
# 1    NaN    fv       up
# 2    NaN    fv    there
# 3  dfasd   NaN  kutfddx
# 4   fdfa   uyg  iutyfrd
```

Comment: Is there any way how to make this bit of code capable of taking NaN and Null values? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to drop NaN values or to do not change them ?

Comment: Not to change them for sure. Thanks

Comment: Great, thanks for this one. Will have to figure out why my python 2.7 (pandas 0.14.1) is not working. I tested it out on my python 3.7 and it worked fine.

Comment: At first glance, rename method: .rename('new_{}'.format(i)) causes problems under Python 2.7 (pandas 0.14.1), it returns following error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

Comment: I had to proceed with naming the series created in for loop like this: tmp.name = 'new_' + i; then it worked as desired.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can `agg` with `itertools.product`

```
import itertools
df.agg(lambda r: pd.Series(list(itertools.product(*[r.a.split(',')], *[r.b.split(',')], *[r.c.split(',')]))), 1).stack().apply(pd.Series).reset_index(drop=True)


    0       1       2
0   Hi      fv      whats
1   Hi      fv      up
2   Hi      fv      there
3   there   fv      whats
4   there   fv      up
5   there   fv      there
6   dfasd   vfgfh   kutfddx
7   fdfa    uyg     iutyfrd
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it works as desired. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to import itertools (can only use pandas and numpy). More general solution to this problem would be replacing hardcoded part of product function.